# Skip a specific test file on travis in R

Tags: r, travis-ci, testthat, rstan

My [testing suite](https://github.com/easystats/insight/tree/dev/tests/testthat) is made of multiple files. I would like to skip one of them on travis (the one related to fitting Bayesian models) because it takes to much time and fails.

I know that I can skip specific tests with `testthat::skip_on_travis()`. However, these work in a test_that block. Unfortunately, the part I wish to skip (from [here](https://github.com/easystats/insight/blob/63c7c7d3f00e4c328021f7894a02d42b59dfaef4/tests/testthat/test-brms.R#L11) to [here](https://github.com/easystats/insight/blob/63c7c7d3f00e4c328021f7894a02d42b59dfaef4/tests/testthat/test-brms.R#L66)) is mainly outside the test_that block (and is the model fitting occurring *before* testing).

I tried putting the model fitting inside a test_that block, but then the other blocks do not find the models. I also tried nested test_that block, but that seems not to work... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option that seems to work is to check the environment variables:

```
if (Sys.getenv("USER") != "travis") {
  # tests to be executed...
}
```

See also here:
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

In your testthat.R file, you can use the `filter` argument to `test_check` in order to skip entire files conditionally. This mechanism can be used to skip collections of long tests on CRAN or Travis.